# One Play button to control two plotly charts

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a simply shiny app and i have two plotly charts there each with its `Play` button.
I need to have one button that would animate both charts. How can I do it?

My code is below:

Plot 1:

```
  output$plot1<-renderPlotly({

    res<-df%>%
      plot_ly(
        x=~year,
        y=~value,
        showlegend = TRUE
      )%>%add_lines()

    res<-res%>%add_trace(
      x=~year,
      frame=~year,
      y=~value,
      color=~state,
      type = 'scatter',
      mode = 'markers',
      showlegend = FALSE
    )
   return(res)

  })
```

Plot 2:

```
  output$plot2<-renderPlotly({


 
   res2<- df2%>%
      plot_ly(
        x=~var,
        y=~var2,
        frame=~year,
        type = 'bar')

     return(res2)

  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("anim", "Animate both plots"),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6,
      plotlyOutput("plot1")
    ),
    column(
      6,
      plotlyOutput("plot2")
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["plot1"]] <- renderPlotly({
    df <- data.frame(
      x = c(1,2,1), 
      y = c(1,2,1), 
      f = c(1,2,3)
    )
    df %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~x,
        y = ~y,
        frame = ~f,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = 20),
        showlegend = FALSE
      ) %>% 
      animation_button(visible = FALSE) %>%
      onRender("
        function(el,x){
          $('#anim').on('click', function(){Plotly.animate(el);});
        }")
  })
  
  output[["plot2"]] <- renderPlotly({
    df <- data.frame(
      x = c(2,1,2), 
      y = c(2,1,2), 
      f = c(1,2,3)
    )
    df %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~x,
        y = ~y,
        frame = ~f,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = 20),
        showlegend = FALSE
      ) %>% 
      animation_button(visible = FALSE) %>%
      onRender("
        function(el,x){
          $('#anim').on('click', function(){Plotly.animate(el);});
        }")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!!! 
have not used htmlwidgets before! looks like amazing library! you made my weekend of learning!
LOVE YOU! ❤️❤️❤️

Comment: You're wrlcome @m45ha. Could you please upvote and accept the answer now?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), hence, I have to improvise.

But with a bit of JavaScript you could:

1. Trigger the play button of the second `plotly` graph whenever the play button of the first `plotly` graph is pressed.
2. Hide the play button and slider altogether of the second graph.

The reprex below does not use `shiny`, but it is rather straight forward to translate that to shiny too:

```r
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk) ## just for bscols
library(htmltools)

## this JavaScript attaches a click handler to the SVG button 
## of the left play button (which fires the second play button)
## and hides the controls for the second graph
js <- HTML("
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const left = document.querySelector('#left .updatemenu-button');
    const right = document.querySelector('#right .updatemenu-button');
    left.addEventListener('click', 
                          () => right.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))); 
    right.style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#right .slider-container').style.display = 'none';
  })
") |>
   tags$script(type = "text/javascript") |>
   tags$head()

df <- data.frame(
   x = c(1, 2, 1), 
   y = c(1, 2, 1), 
   f = c(1, 2, 3)
)

fig1 <- fig2 <- df %>%
   plot_ly(
      x = ~x,
      y = ~y,
      frame = ~f,
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "markers",
      showlegend = FALSE
   )

## I use bscols here just to quickly layout 2 plots and add some JS
## In your shiny app you won't need that most probably
bscols(div(fig1, id = "left"),
       div(fig2, id = "right"), 
       js)
```

Comment: never used crosstalk :( how would you translate it to shiny?

Comment: you just need to include the JavaScript in your `ui` for instance by adding `tags$head(tags$script(js, type = "text/javascript"))` to your ui. Make sure that the `plotlyOutput` sits in a div with the `id` as highlighted above and the `JS` will work out of the box. (in `shiny` the additional `div` may not be needed and you could adapt the `css` seletcors to benefit from the id associated to the `plotlyOutput` but this is out of scope for this answer)

Answer (score -1):

Since you did not give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), try this app below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("click", "Click to refresh")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the slider value
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1"),
      plotOutput("plot2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    input$click
    dist <- rnorm(100)
    hist(dist)
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    input$click
    dist <- rnorm(100)
    plot(dist)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

All you need to do is simple: add two plot rendering to one input as ["reactive dependency"](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html#the-reactive-graph)(in this case, `input$click`), so that each time `input$click` updates, the two plots will be re-rendered.